# Jquery and making a cover div go above all content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so i've been struggling with jquery and making a div that's suppose to cover the page on click. I know how to cover the whole page with a div on top (higher z-index, a bit of opacity and vuala), i have a button, but how to I make it work when clicked.. https://jsfiddle.net/4uu8Lkdt/8/ appreciate the help. I've tried doing

```
$('#id').click(function() {
  $('#id').toggleClass('cover');
  document.getElementById("cover").style.zIndex = 1;
});
```

but it didn't work.. I'm new at this website development and javascript stuff.

Comment: While this won't necessarily answer your question, it might be worth reading up on how z-index works since it's not as simple as one might think, because there can be different stacking contexts. http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: The code you linked to doesn't contain any elements with an ID of `id` and you haven't defined a CSS class of `cover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small edit for your code including jQuery (question is tagged for it):

https://jsfiddle.net/4uu8Lkdt/9/

```
if (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) {
    $('body').append($('<div class="cover">'));
} else {
    $('.cover').remove();
}
```

New CSS class for cover:

```
.cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 11;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: white;
}
```

I would recommend changing the code to jQuery equivalents. It's much easier for developing.

Comment: Wow...so basically what i had to do was include some code from the button code instead of 'toggleclass'..? I'll be using that cover 'page' as a quick menu, so i'll have to add a simple navigation, will that cause some problems in showing and hiding the page? Also, is it possible to make the cover come in smoothly, slowly, in a second or something?

Comment: Everything is possible with jQuery. It's super easy to use, especially as a beginner. There is a great documentation with many examples: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check it here https://jsfiddle.net/4uu8Lkdt/13/

This jQuery is added

```
$('.c-hamburger').on('click', function(){
  $('.cover').toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

And you should add your z-index and whatever you need for that cover class that I also added in css.

**Edit**

CSS in jsfiddle is updated so cover div goes over your image.